# How to improve select range of values if one one of them have specific variable in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select

My question is how can i speed this up. There should be more elegant way to handle it. 
The inner select is done in  0,038 sec but this one is done in 6,007 sec i dont know how can i improve this performace

```
select * FROM table
where number1 in (
SELECT number1 
FROM table
WHERE `date` = 'yyyy-mm-dd' 
AND value1 = 'variable1' 
AND value2 = 1
)
```

the thing is that i need range of values from the same table if one contains in the value2 the variable 1

so from table like that

```
id|number1| value1   | value2
1 | 11403 | exempl1  |  null
2 | 11404 | exempl1  | 1
3 | 11404 | exempl1  | null
4 | 11405 | exempl1  | null
5 | 11405 | exempl1  | null
```

i get only this

```
id|number1| value1   | value2
2 | 11404 | exempl1  | 1
3 | 11404 | exempl1  | null
```

Comment: And what result do you want?

Comment: Improve performance. There should be a way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it into [Correlated Subquery with Exists](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html). MySQL optimizer *may* be able to use Indexes (if defined) in this case.

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table AS t1
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1 
              FROM table AS t2
              WHERE t2.number1 = t1.number1 AND 
                    t2.`date` = 'yyyy-mm-dd' AND 
                    t2.value1 = 'variable1' AND 
                    t2.value2 = 1 )
```

If indexes are not defined, you can define a Composite Index on `(number1, date, value1, value2)`, for better performance.

```
ALTER TABLE `table`
ADD INDEX comp_idx1(number1, `date`, value1, value2);
```

Another optimization possibility is to fetch only those columns which are really required in your application code. Avoid using `SELECT *`. You may read: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Comment: there is no improvement in performance, it works but still over 6 seconds downtime.

Comment: @arudiel Do you have the indexing defined on the columns ? Add the composite index as specified in my answer.

Comment: At first i was thinking it helped but after testing there is the same problem as for the standard select by value. In the solution @Madhur Bhaiya sugested afted adding the id colum only shows the ID that have met the statment values not the whole rows.

Comment: @arudiel check my solution; I have never used `ID` at all. I dont know why are you matching `ID`. It will kill all the purpose

Comment: @arudiel add the Index (`alter table` statement) which I have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I have indexed only Id , date , value1 columns. 

So the end code looks like
t2.date = t1.date AND 
t2.date = 'yyyy-mm-dd' AND

Comment: @arudiel query is fine. You are concerned about performance, right ?

Comment: @arudiel then please run this statement to add an index: `ALTER TABLE your_table_name_here
ADD INDEX comp_idx1(number1, date, value1, value2);`

Comment: Done and i think worked. But i dont understand this i have indexes on those fields only separated indiwidualy. Whats the diference ?

Comment: @arudiel Go through this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html